# Rendering Issue in Android Studio of using custom fonts

Tags: java, android, fonts, rendering

I am using a custom fonts in my app.
I found the error below in my layout design page.
The fonts seem OK on my device, but it might make some issues in other devices.

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue and what impact the issue would make if I cannot resolve this one.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Font not found D:\Work\Good Husband\4.1
>   Android
>   Porgramming\goodhus\app\src\main\res\font\modern_gothic_otf_r.otf     at
>   android.graphics.Typeface.createFromFile(Typeface.java:885)   at
>   android.graphics.Typeface_Delegate.create(Typeface_Delegate.java:239)
>     at android.graphics.Typeface.create(Typeface.java:676)  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.updateTypefaceAndStyle(AppCompatTextHelper.java:245)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:165)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:76)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:66)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:215)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:218)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:336)
>     at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:155)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:225)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:204)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:900)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:859)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:547)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:681)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)